# How do you set up a database schema when one object is shared by two or more in Grails?

Tags: grails, model, associations, grails-orm, shared

I would really appreciate if you can help me with a problem or can show me better way to do it.
So basically I have 3 models,

```
Class Person {
         String firstName
         String lastName
         ...
         Address personalAdd
}

Class Business {
        String businessName
        String BusinessType
        ....
        Address BusinessAdd
}
```

now this 2 models are sharing one common model,

```
Class Address {
        String Street
        String zip
        ...
}
```

Now when I save business or person, it still shows that Address.list().size() == 0 in unit-testing.
When I explicitly save the object as,

```
address.save(flush: true)
new Business(... ... ..., address: address).save(flush:true)
```

it works fine, 
but then when I delete it doesn't get deleted either. I tried cascade 'all-delete-orphan' and 'delete', didn't work, I also tried,

```
Class Business {

      ....
      def beforeDelete() {
           Address.withNewSession {
            Address.load(address.id).delete()
        }
      }
     .....
}
```

But still no expected output!
What should i do? to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your properties aren't linked by any `hasMany` or `belongsTo` relationships and are therefore handled independently. And you can't set a `belongsTo` on an address anyway (it has different parents). So what are your options?

You can keep the entitites separate (as you have them now) and handle the relationships manually ([GORM events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) can help you there).

You can [embed](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#gormComposition) the `Address` into both the `Person` and the `Business` class. If you need the addresses to be in their own tables though, that won't work.

Or you can subclass `Address` and have for example:

```
class BusinessAddress extends Address {
    static belongsTo = [ business: Business ]
}
```

.. and

```
class PersonAddress extends Address {
    static belongsTo = [ person: Person ]
}
```

This way you would have only one table with addresses in the database.